# Ubuntu 19.04 Login Loop

Tags: system-installation

After updating to 19.04 I have a login loop on the existing account. I created a new account and it works without an problems. How can I repair the other account so that the login to GUI will work again?

Comment: A gui login creates working files in $HOME.  If there is no space there, it'll fail (and you are logged out without message; ie. login-loop). How did you login to the other account? as text-logins don't create the work-files so will proceed.  Login via [text] terminal to ensure you have space, or if you can't login there, there are different issues (can you `su` across from the other account to your wanted account...)

Answer (score 9):

This is by no means the only possible fix but after lots of googling I came across the suggestion that the profile was somehow corrupted. The fix was to

1. cd .local/share
2. Move gnome-shell to gnome-shell-old.
3. Restart laptop and login to messed up account.

In my case that fix worked (a new gnome-shell was created) so I deleted gnome-shell-old.

I apologize for not providing a link. I found this earlier in the day using my tablet.